# Why am I being redirected to Cisco Guest Access

Tags: wireless-networking, internet

Every time I access the internet, the neighbor's Cisco GUEST ACCESS shows up instead of my home internet.  If I leave my computer for over 15 minutes, I am kicked off my own internet ID and redirected to the neighbor's Cisco  Guest Access!  I am fed up with this annoying problem. How and why can Cisco  override my own internet?

Comment: Ask your neighbor to disable their guest access on their router and/or stop trying to connect to their wireless connection.

Comment: Have you tried to use the SSID hiding feaure? Don't do that.

Answer (score 1):

Nearly every OS maintains a list of previously connected wireless connections you have connected to - if whatever connection you are on drops, it will connect to the next one in order it can find that you have previously joined.

If you never want to connect to your neighbours wifi, simply delete them from the list - I can't really give more advice on how to do this as you haven't said which OS you are using.

Cisco isn't overriding your internet, it sounds like you just have a bad router/access point and your connection is dropping which is causing your machine to redirect to your neighbours.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your Pc is set to automatically connect to open wifi networks. Have a look at this page http://m.wikihow.com/Prevent-Windows-from-Connecting-to-Unsecured-Wireless-Networks for how to stop it.